# What is the best way to configure an application startup.cs to use both Azure AD and Azure B2C in .netcore? I am new to Identiy providers

Tags: .net-core, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-web

What is the best way to configure an application startup.cs to use both Azure AD and Azure B2C in .netcore? I see a lot of referencing indictating to use only Azure B2C, but due to the circumstances I need to use both Identity providers separately giving the users the option to choose which service.
But I am not sure how to go about it, and after configuring the startup, how would I use distinct "Authorize" on the actions within the same controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that adding multiple Azure Active Directory authentication providers in the same app using the current release of the Microsoft Identity Web library is not available (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/549 ) but will hopefully be added soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure AD B2C custom policy and [Azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) can be set as an identity provider.The end result is as shown below, where users can choose to log in with an ad account.
[image]

Comment: I need azure Ad distinct and separate from b2c. In other words, I am not trying to allow azure ad as a way to sign in through b2c

Comment: Why not, your approach increases complexity as you have to handle two token issuers instead of one. The only reason I see taking your approach is if you need those AAD users to call some Microsoft owned API.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I agree, but as it was told to me, there were issues outside of our control in regards to syncing roles/groups with AD through b2c and back to on prem. I eventually found a solution through an example using Microsoft's Identity Web package using a preview release: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki

Comment: Instead you would control the groups in AD->AAD as normal, and pass group information from the AAD token into the B2C token using the aforementioned federation approach.